# How to make functional components into class components?

Tags: reactjs

I have buttons that slide the page down by clicking and then this part becomes a different color thanks to CSS.
But the fact is that these components are functional and I need class components.
How to make functional components into class components?

React:

```
const ScrollButton = props => {
  const onClick = () => window.scrollTo({
    top: props.scrollTo,
    behavior: 'smooth',
  });

  return (
    <div className="down" style={{ top: `${props.top}px` }}>
      <div className="down-text">Scroll to {props.scrollTo}
        <button onClick={onClick}>&#10095;</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => (
  <div className="container">
    <ScrollButton scrollTo={500} top={50} />
    <ScrollButton scrollTo={1000} top={100} />
    <ScrollButton scrollTo={2000} top={200} />
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

СSS:

```
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.container{
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, yellow, red);
  height: 3000px;
  width: 100%;
}

.down {
  position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Why you need class component? From React 16.8, whatever you used to do with class component you can do the same with functional component.

Comment: What have you tried?  The tutorial on the React website shows how to make simple components.  Did you try making one?  Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I'm just starting to study react, and I've been learning to make class components and I've never done functional ones so I don't know how to remake

Comment: @stelach: *"I've been learning to make class components"* - So... You're learning how to make class components, and you're asking us how to make a class component?  Sounds like you need to at least *attempt* to apply the knowledge you're learning.  Stack Overflow is not a replacement for tutorials.  If you're learning how to make components, then try to make a component.  If you encounter a specific error or unexpected result that you don't understand, we can help with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i created a functional component to Class components.

```
<pre>
<code>
class ScrollButton extends React.Component {
  onClick() {
    window.scrollTo({
      top: this.props.scrollTo,
      behavior: 'smooth',
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <div className="down" style={{ top: `${this.props.top}px` }}>
      <div className="down-text">Scroll to {this.props.scrollTo}
         <button onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}> &#10095;</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
  }
}

const App = () => (
  <div className="container">
    <ScrollButton scrollTo={500} top={50} />
    <ScrollButton scrollTo={1000} top={100} />
    <ScrollButton scrollTo={2000} top={200} />
  </div>
);
</code>
</pre>
```